# Average or calculate average

Tags: mysql, sql, average, mean

Is there a way to get average number of something if it isn't numbers?
My table:

```
ID|  CAT  |  TITLE  |     DATE            |
--|-------|---------|---------------------|
1 | CAT01 | TITLE01 | 2013-01-18 20:37:15 |
2 | CAT01 | TITLE02 | 2013-01-18 20:37:16 |
3 | CAT02 | TITLE03 | 2013-01-19 12:09:54 |
```

How could I get the AVG of posts per day?
For now I am using this:

```
SELECT AVG(cat) / DATEDIFF('2013-01-19', '2013-01-18') as average 
FROM posts 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-01-18' AND '2013-01-19'"
```

But for me it does not return average count. Maybe I should first count(cat) AS cnt and then use avg(cnt) AS average?
Or the AVG can not be used on non number tables?

Comment: You can do a group by DATE formatting the date yyyy-MM-dd and count every CAT, with this count you can get the average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one step. A tested example may be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05760/12

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) / 
  COUNT(DISTINCT cast(`date` as date)) avg_posts_per_day
FROM 
  posts
```

---

Or you can do this in two steps:

1. get posts per day,
2. average the result of step 1.

A tested example may be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05760/4

```
SELECT 
  AVG(posts_per_day) AS AVG_POSTS_PER_DAY
FROM (    
  SELECT 
    CAST(`date` as date), 
    COUNT(*) posts_per_day
  FROM posts  
  GROUP BY 
    CAST(`date` as date)
) ppd
```

Comment: `posts_per_day` just an alias (nickname) for the result of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @bernie I am not sure if this is always correct... if instead of date='2013-01-18' we use '2013-01-17' it still counts 1.5 (because 18 is not present and isn't counted), but I think it should return 1 (3 posts, in 3 days) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d57/16

Comment: @fthiella: It depends on the intent, right? The denominator could be 1) the number of days with posts (as in my answer), or 2) the total number of days elapsed (as in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT COUNT(cat)/2  as avrag
   FROM posts
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bc67a/2)

EDIT:

and if you want use the average between two dates just add this

```
     where date between 'the_date1' AND 'the_date2'
```

Comment: Well it works but the table I gave is just an example. At moment it has 146 rows. So it doesnt give me the average. It just divides it by 2.

Comment: i said if u want average between some two dates , just add my WHERE clause or what you want exactly ?

Comment: you want average per day? or per given two dates?

Comment: I already stated that I need per day. But thanks for helping man!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the get the number of total posts, the number of days since the first timestamp in your database, and calculate an average from those two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to count the number of rows with `COUNT(*)`, and add 1 to datediff:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / (DATEDIFF('2013-01-19', '2013-01-18')+1) as average 
FROM posts 
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2013-01-18' AND '2013-01-19'
```

This will return the average number of posts, days that have no posts are counted.

Or, depending on what you are after, you might consider something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) /
  (datediff(max(`date`), min(`date`))+1) as avg_posts
FROM
  posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, formatted date yyyy-MM-dd to count all post per day and then take the average of each day

```
SELECT 
   amount/total AS AVG_POSTS_PER_DAY, day
FROM
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) amount, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d') day,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) from posts) total
  FROM posts
  group by
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d')) a
group by day`
```